# onイベントに関数名を付けた場合の引数の渡し方を教えてください。

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function push() {
    let hoge = 1;
    $('#selector').on('click', buttonPush);
};

function buttonPush(hoge) {
     hoge++;
     changeNumber(hoge);
};
```

上記のように、onイベントで呼び出した名前付きの関数に、どのように記述したら引数を渡せるのでしょうか。

```
function push() {
    let hoge = 1;
    $('#selector').on('click', funcition(hoge){
         hoge++;
         changeNumber(hoge);
    });
};
```

ネットで調べると、上記のような無名関数の場合の書き方は散見されましたが、名前付きの関数の場合の書き方が見つけられず、質問した次第です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

イベントハンドラの引数を束縛する場合、 `Function.prototype.bind` メソッドを使うことが出来ます。

```js
function push() {
  let hoge = 1;
  $("#selector").on("click", buttonPush.bind(this, {hoge}));
}

function buttonPush(args, event) {
  args.hoge++;
  changeNumber(args.hoge);
}
```

もし jQuery を使用しているのであれば、 `event.data` オブジェクトを使うことも出来ます。

```
function push() {
  let hoge = 1;
  $("#selector").on("click", {hoge}, buttonPush);
}

function buttonPush(event) {
  event.data.hoge++;
  changeNumber(event.data.hoge);
}
```

また、 `$.proxy` メソッドを使うことも出来ます。

```
function push() {
  let hoge = 1;
  $("#selector").on("click", $.proxy(buttonPush, null, {hoge}));
}

function buttonPush(args, event) {
  args.hoge++;
  changeNumber(args.hoge);
}
```